# Python program to create dictionary from list counting digits after character

Tags: python

I need to build a function that will create a dictionary from a list of characters and digits, where each key is the character string and each value is the number of digits following that string.

For example, given the list':

```
lst = ['tiger',4,2,6,'elephant',7,1,'bear',2,4,5,1]
```

I want to get:

```
{tiger: 3, elephant:2, bear:4}
```

I first tried using a for loop to pull out the "keys" but am stuck on the next step and wondering if there is an easier way:

```
def getkeys(str1):
    keys=[]
    for x in str1:
        if x not in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
            i = x.split(' ')
            res = keys.append(i)
    return(keys)

getkeys(lst)
#returns: [['tiger'], ['elephant'], ['bear']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using a conditional check on if an item is a string. This assumes that `lst[0]` is a string.

```
out = {}
for x in lst:
    if isinstance(x, str):
        out[x] = 0
        current = x
    else:
        out[current] += 1
```

Output:

```
{'tiger': 3, 'elephant': 2, 'bear': 4}
```